# Android percent layouts

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to create a layout that would looks like this:

```
-- Scrollview --
-------Top -----
 [Image view 1]
    n% margin
 [Image view 2]
    m% margin
 [Image view 3] 
    l% margin
------Bottom----
-- /Scrollview--
```

With Image View adapting their height to the image aspect ratio, filling 100% width.

This is the layout I use:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.motionportrait.hokuto_malts.ChooseVideoActivity">

    <ScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <android.support.percent.PercentFrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         >
            <ImageView
                       android:id="@+id/choose_movie_1"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       app:layout_marginTopPercent="0%"
                       android:layout_width="match_parent"
                       android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                       android:onClick="play"
                      />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/choose_movie_2"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                app:layout_marginTopPercent="20%"
                android:onClick="play"
            />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/choose_movie_3"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                app:layout_marginTopPercent="40%"
                android:onClick="play"/>
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/choose_movie_4"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                app:layout_marginTopPercent="60%"
                android:onClick="play"/>
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/choose_movie_5"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                app:layout_marginTopPercent="80%"
                android:onClick="play"/>


        </android.support.percent.PercentFrameLayout>

</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

However using this layout, the top margin isn't taken into account and every image are squashed on top of the view.

My requirement is to be able to define % margins since I need the pictures to partially cover themselves

Comment: Try to check this link : https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/know-percent-support-library/en

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I'm sorry, I .. forgot to add the question at the end. Edited. Now taking a look at all the answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I endup using.

The trick lies in `app:layout_widthPercent="100%"` 
Without this, it seems the view cannot size properly

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.motionportrait.hokuto_malts.ChooseVideoActivity">
    <ScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <android.support.percent.PercentFrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         >
            <android.support.percent.PercentFrameLayout
                app:layout_aspectRatio="21%"
                app:layout_widthPercent="100%"
            >
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/choose_movie_1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_marginTopPercent="4.5%"
                    android:src="@drawable/movie01"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:onClick="play"
                />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/choose_movie_title"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
                <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/choose_movie_2"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:src="@drawable/movie02"
                app:layout_marginTopPercent="19%"
                android:onClick="play"
            />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/choose_movie_3"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/movie03"
                app:layout_marginTopPercent="38%"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:onClick="play"/>
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/choose_movie_5"
                    android:src="@drawable/movie05"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    app:layout_marginTopPercent="74.5%"
                    android:onClick="play"/>
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/choose_movie_4"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/movie04"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                app:layout_marginTopPercent="55%"
                android:onClick="play"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:src="@drawable/back_manga"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:onClick="back"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

            </android.support.percent.PercentFrameLayout>
        </android.support.percent.PercentFrameLayout>

</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:scaleType="fitXY"` for your `Imageview` to adapting their height to the image aspect ratio.

Comment: The images are correctly sized; only the layout isn't

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@id/img"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
```

Comment: My issue is with the margins, not with the image aspect/sizing

Answer (score 0):

you can simply change your `android.support.percent.PercentFrameLayout` to `LinearLayout`

you can use

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
```

instead of

```
<android.support.percent.PercentFrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

that is simple :-)

you can further use `android:layout_weight` also.

if still any query, please feel free to ask.
happy coding :-)

Comment: I'm sorry my question was unclear. I can't use anything else than a frame layout since I need views to be partially a top of each other